# Log4j gradle plugin - "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders()[Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

[image]

I used

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.7.5'
```

in build.gradle file

Now when it is downloading dependency there is difference in version of log4j-api and log4j-core

and this is creating exception of

`ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for ctx java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders()[Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;`

and when the same version of plugin i used as maven so it wont have any issue and application is running fine

**any fix for gradle**

[image]

Comment: Looks like you use incompatible libraries.

Comment: yes i know while using gradle it is downloading org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api2.18.2
i need 2.17.2

Comment: Add it as a dependency.

Comment: Can you please show your build.gradle file